# Executing the same SQL select for multiple parameters specified

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Oh Great SQL experts, I have the following scenario. I have to do the same select, multiple times and only a parameter (S) changes each time, Example:

```
DECLARE @company1 varchar(25)
set @company1 = AA
```

then run the following:

```
Select * from sales where Company_Name = @company1
```

declare a new paramater

```
 set @company1 = BB
```

and loop back to run the query.

This can be for a few companies, and possibly a few parameters per run.
So all that I want to do is to specify the query once, and just add the @companyX declaration on top.

Thanks

Comment: How is the parameter being populated with different values? Can you show your whole procedure?

Answer (score 0):

There is little information in the question on the context of how the data is provided to the parameters or the query so here are some options.

Create a stored procedure, and call it multiple times:

```
-- Stored procedure
create procedure dbo.GetSalesByCompany
@companyName varchar(25)

AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;
Select * from sales where Company_Name = @company1;

--Usage
exec dbo.GetSalesByCompany 'AA';
exec dbo.GetSalesByCompany 'BB';

-- Usage with params
DECLARE @company1 varchar(25)
set @company1 = 'AA';
exec dbo.GetSalesByCompany @company1;
set @company1 = 'BB';
exec dbo.GetSalesByCompany @company1;
```

Create a user defined table-valued function.  this can be called from stored procedures if needed:

```
-- User defined table-valued function
Create Function dbo.udf_GetSalesByCompany
(@companyName varchar(25) )

RETURNS TABLE AS
RETURN Select * from sales where Company_Name = @company1;

--Usage
SELECT * FROM dbo.udf_GetSalesByCompany('AA');
SELECT * FROM dbo.udf_GetSalesByCompany('BB');

-- Usage with params
DECLARE @company1 varchar(25)
set @company1 = 'AA';
SELECT * FROM dbo.udf_GetSalesByCompany(@company1);
set @company1 = 'BB';
SELECT * FROM dbo.udf_GetSalesByCompany(@company1);
```

Or you an "IN" statement to get to call the query once, for multiple filters values, in this case, company names.

```
--Use and "IN" statement
Select * from sales where Company_Name IN('AA', 'BB')
```